# I have multiple Outlook accounts for different aspects of my role and want to generate an alert in 1 inbox when mail is received into another

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook

I would like to generate an alert in my 'benenden.school' email inbox when mail is received into my 'benenden.international' inbox so that I'm aware that I need to check the second inbox.

Please may you advise how I can do this?

I need to send instructions to the other 3 staff members who also have 'benenden.school' and 'benenden.international' accounts so that they remember to check both inboxes.

Many thanks.

Comment: Use an Outlook Rule. Outlook, Rules, use Sent to (you) and then as an outcome of the rule, forward the email to yourself in the other email account.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with John mentioned above, creating an Outlook forward rule should be able to help. By the way, if you are using Outlook desktop client, you can configure several email accounts into one Outlook profile at the same time. Once you receive new emails, you will get a desktop alert for them. Also you can using Outlook rules to display New Item Alert window.

[image]

Comment: Have you got your issue fixed? If you think my reply is helpful to you, please remember to mark it as an answer. Thanks for your understanding and support.